# how to read from database table in system.xml for config?

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, database, configuration, system.xml

I want to use 2 tables in database for system.xml in my module as `toOptionArray` only for adminhtml config, how can I use it?

it work same as origin country and state ins shipping settings but want use my own table and they are states and cities, means when I select region from dropdown then cities of this state load and I can select one of them

Created 2 table in databse with the name of `directory_region` and `directory_region_city` and inserted `region_id` , `region_name` , `code` , `city_id` , `city_name` in these 2 tables

Answer (score 3):

When defining your field in your `system.xml` file you can specify the `source_model` of this field. For example the source model for the standard yes no drop down is as follows.

```
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
```

This will tell the field to use the model `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno` for building the options. Inside this model you will see the function `toOptionArray` which

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno
{

    /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes')),
            array('value' => 0, 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No')),
        );
    }
}
```

So using this as a basis for your requirements what you can do is set-up your own model for example `Your_Module_Model_System_Config_Region`, then you would simply need to use your table's collection to build the correct structure in the function `toOptionArray`.

As far as loading one source model based on the value of another you have two options.

**Using Frontend Models**

Perfect example of this is the tax options for country and region under `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/etc/system.xml`.

Basically what you need to do is create a frontend_model that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field`. This block will only need to have the function `_getElementHtml`. What you can do then is call the parent function so the default select is created and show and then add some javascript that will update this select based on when another element has changed.

In the tax example it uses the standard `RegionUpdater` but it is possible to work with the more generic `SelectUpdater` which allows for one select element to change another.

Now I will show you in depth how this can be achieved. In this example I am using the magento standard country and region collections but you can easily plug in your own collections when needed.

Firstly you will need the system.xml, this should add the correct `frontend_model` and `source_model` references:

```
<config>
    <tabs>
        <example>
            <label>Example</label>
        </example>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <example translate="label" module="example_frontendmodel">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Example</label>
            <tab>example</tab>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <frontend_model translate="label">
                    <label>Frontend Model</label>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <country translate="label">
                            <label>Default Country</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>example_frontendmodel/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </country>
                        <region translate="label">
                            <label>Default State</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <frontend_model>example_frontendmodel/adminhtml_frontend_region_updater</frontend_model>
                            <source_model>example_frontendmodel/system_config_source_region</source_model>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </region>
                    </fields>
                </frontend_model>
            </groups>
        </example>
    </sections>
</config>
```

For this example the two source_models are the same as the standard `Mage_Tax` source models so there is nothing special there. But you could here load all the options you need for from your tables.

The next thing of importance is the `frontend_model` here what you do is extend the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field` and create your own `_getElementHtml` function. This function will call the parent `_getElementHtml` and set a variable with the returned html. Then you can build your javascript using the `SelectUpdater` you can see from the init, in file `js/mage/adminhtml/form.js`, that you need to specify the following.

1. The first select element's id,
2. The second select element's id,
3. A default message for use on the second select when the first one is not selected,
4. A message to use if the selection from the first select element does not have a match in the second,
5. The values for the second element json encoded,
6. The current selected item,

My example looks as follows.

```
<?php

class Example_FrontendModel_Block_Adminhtml_Frontend_Region_Updater
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $html = parent::_getElementHtml($element);

        $js = '<script type="text/javascript">
            var updater = new SelectUpdater(
                "example_frontend_model_country",
                "example_frontend_model_region",
                "none",
                "none",
                %s,
                false
            );
            updater.update();
        </script>';

        $html .= sprintf($js, $this->helper('example_frontendmodel')->getRegionJson());
        return $html;
    }
}
```

The values are built from my helper and replaced into the html string just before being returned. The easiest way to build the values is to create an array of the following format.

```
array(
    'first_select_value1' => array(
        'second_select_value1' => 'second_select_text1',
        'second_select_value2' => 'second_select_text2',
    ),
    'first_select_value2' => array(
        'second_select_value3' => 'second_select_text3',
        'second_select_value4' => 'second_select_text4',
    )
)
```

Here is my example's helper for building the values, but you could easily extend it to use what ever collections you need for your need.

```
<?php
class Example_FrontendModel_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function getRegionJson()
    {
        /**
         * array(
         *  'first_value' => array(
         *      'second_value' => 'second_txt'
         *  )
         * )
         */
        $countryIds = array();
        $countryCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getResourceCollection()
            ->loadByStore();
        foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
            $countryIds[] = $country->getCountryId();
        }
        $collection = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()
            ->addCountryFilter($countryIds)
            ->load();
        $regions = array();
        foreach ($collection as $region) {
            if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $regions[$region->getCountryId()][$region->getRegionId()] = $this->__($region->getName());
        }
        return Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($regions);
    }
}
```

Comment: city filed is not single city, it must be selectable list, same as regions

Comment: @sIiiS yes, that is why I added the source_model to all the city fields, make these also of type select and this will work.

Comment: when I add source_model to city fields, then page do not load and I got error "Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in... \core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php on line 463"

Comment: @sIiiS did you fill in the rest of the xml or just copy my example as it did not include all sections

Comment: no, it has complete fields that need, this is my code for regions `<originstate translate="label"><source_model>module/carrier_module_source_originregion</source_model></originstate>` and for cities `<city_1 translate="label"><frontend_type>select</frontend_type><source_model>module/carrier_module_source_origincity_1</source_model><depends><originstate><value>41</value></originstate></depends></city_1>` and `<city_2 translate="label">....<source_model>module/carrier_module_source_origincity_2</source_model>....<depends><originstate><value>41</value></originstate></depends></city_2>`

Comment: I think this is not good idea, because I have 30 regions and every region has more than 10 cities!

Comment: Yeah that is my worry also.

Comment: If I can read info from database can solve the problem, same as country or regions as depend on country

Comment: @sIiiS you can read items from the database from the source model but as I pointed out in the answer you would have to always save the regoin before you could show the correct city information.

Comment: yes, but it must load same as your second solution, and first solution is not good for me

Comment: Frontend_model would probably be your best bet

Comment: Ooops! it is very difficult for me! , I am not professional php programmer!